# como usar o date interval para contar dias?

Tags: php, mysql

como posso usar o `date interval` para contar quando se cadastrar um produto, por exemplo eu cadastro o produto dia 8 quero que daqui 15 dias esse produto deixe de ser um produto novo ou seja quando for dia 23 esse produto não e mais novo como posso fazer isso usando o `date interval`?

codigo :

```
 $criacao_produto = new DateTime($data);
 $dias = $criacao_produto->diff(new DateTime())->d;
    if($dias < 2)
      echo "Produto e novo";
    else
      echo "produto velho"
```

Comment: Precisa ser com date interval não pode ser via PHP?

Comment: Ou você quer só um countdown?

Comment: Não é simples calcular a diferença da data de criação e data de hoje?

Comment: pode também ser via php e que eu não sei qual seria o mais fácil para fazer. e tipo e só um countdown também por que eu quero q ele pegue a data de hoje e conte 15 dias

Comment: como que posso fazer para calcular a diferença das datas estou vendo tutoriais na internet e tipo só acho desse modelo:  $data_inicial = '2013-08-01';
 $data_final = '2013-08-16';

 // Calcula a diferença em segundos entre as datas
 $diferenca = strtotime($data_final) - strtotime($data_inicial);

 //Calcula a diferença em dias
 $dias = floor($diferenca / (60 * 60 * 24));

 echo "A diferença é de $dias entre as datas";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode pegar a data de criação do produto e calcular a diferença(comparado a hoje) com `diff()`

```
<?php

$produto = new stdClass();
$produto->dataCriacao = new DateTime('2015-10-01');

$dias = $produto->dataCriacao->diff(new DateTime())->d;
if($dias >= 15){
    echo "produto velho, adiciado há $dias dias";
}else{
    echo "produto adicionado há $dias dias";
}
```

Ou de forma simplificada:

```
$criacao_produto = new DateTime('2015-10-01');
$dias = $criacao_produto->diff(new DateTime())->d;
echo "criado há $dias dias";
```

Comment: perai deixa eu tentar intender me ajuda ai. dentro desse $produto->dataCriacao = new dateTime(' '); eu devo passar a minha variavel que estou recuperando do banco de dados ou seja a variavel que esta guardando a data? e por que o do $produto = new stdClass(); isto nao deveria ser usado como uma instancia de classe?

Comment: @LeonardoCosta é isso mesmo, criei um objeto produto, da pra faze de forma procedural, já altero a pergunta.

Comment: aparentemente ocoreu tudo bem agora e esperar os dias para ver se nao vai dar error

Comment: Esperar como assim? isso vai rodar em uma rotina agendada pelo cron job algo assim? @LeonardoCosta

Comment: tipo rodar os dias eu coloquei um produto hoje ai tipo vou esperar ate domingo pra ele rodar 2 dias ai ele tem que sair do novo e entrar pro velho vou te mostrar como ficou meu código vo editar a pergunta

Comment: pronto editei a pergunta de uma olhada

Answer (score 1):

Se pretender em MYSQL tem o DATEDIFF. Usar a função.:

```
DATEDIFF(data1,data2)
```

irá returnar os dias de diferença.

Exemplo de uso.:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2016-10-09','2016-10-01') AS QuantidadeDias
```

Resultado = 8

Para o exemplo que deu:

```
Select CASE WHEN  DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),DataProduto)<15 THEN 'Sim' ELSE 'Não' END AS Novo
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui um exemplo de countdown em jquery:

**http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/wvfkbmf5/**

E outro em Angular JS:

**http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/1cyxoytv/**